# Need help to extract information by using regex

Tags: php, regex, tags

need to extract uid value from,

> `!<help><uid=218343><num=685483><arr=(a,g,d)>`

using regx in php how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is as coherent as in your example, it's fairly easy with:

```
preg_match_all('#<(\w+)=([^>]+)>#', $str, $match);
$values = array_combine($match[1], $match[2]);

print $values["uid"];
```

The preg_match_all trick has the advantage that you can access any existing data pair afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/<uid=(\d+)>/", $string, $matches);
$uid = $matches[1];
```